# Binary mask oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I have a SQL command in SQL-Server, and I need to migrate it to Oracle, but there's a part of the sql that I don't understand how to translate it. Here's the sql:

```
select * from myTable where id = @id and (Mask & @Mask) = @Mask
```

I think that It's a binary mask, but I'm not quite sure and I don't know if I can do that in Oracle, could you help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct - this is binary mask.

Oracle provides only BITAND function, others (BITOR, BITXOR) must be self made.

Using BITAND function this select will return value 2:

```
SELECT BITAND(6,2) FROM DUAL;
```

So your query in Oracle can be rewritten in following way:

```
select * from myTable where id = :id and BITAND(Mask, :Mask) = :Mask
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was about to answer my question with that link :D But it's perfect that anyone tells me that i was right. Thank you again